# Version of Java not matching up

Tags: java, version

I installed Sun Java Jre 6 from the source. According to the icon under the Applications menu, it is called "Sun Java 6". Yet, the java -version command yields:

java version "1.5.0"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.5.4

First off, why is Java not 1.6? Also, what is gij?

Comment: Perhaps provide some details on how you installed Java?  For reference, `gij` is the interpreter associated with the `gcj` compiler.

Comment: What exactly is gcj? I installed it by downloading a .tar.gz of Java 6 and installed it from there.

Comment: GCJ is a Java compiler that is part of the GCC tool chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I ran

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and found that my java was not selected. I selected it and now java -version returns 1.6.

Answer (score -1):

Just follow these simple steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin
```

Ubuntu doesn't ship Sun Java because it's not totally free.

There's more information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java). I suggest you read it.

Comment: This isn't particularly good advice given https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/2011-December/001528.html